# Shorten redundant switch statements

Tags: c#, wpf

I got this block of code from a solution I google for a problem I was searching regarding spaghetti `if..else` statements. Is there a way to shorten this at all or a different approach to make the code more maintainable atleast.

```
            switch (registerControl.Valid_FullName(student.Student_Name) == true)
            {
                case true:
                    lblFullNameError.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    break;
                case false:
                    lblFullNameError.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    break;
            }

            switch (registerControl.Valid_Email(student.Student_Email) == true)
            {
                case true:
                    lblEmailError.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    break;
                case false:
                    lblEmailError.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    break;
            }

            switch (registerControl.Valid_Course(student.Student_Course) == true)
            {
                case true:
                    lblCourseError.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    break;
                case false:
                    lblCourseError.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    break;
            }

            switch (registerControl.Valid_Password(student.Student_Password) == true)
            {
                case true:
                    lblPasswordError.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    break;
                case false:
                    lblPasswordError.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    break;
            }

            switch (registerControl.Confirm_Password(student.Student_Password, student.student_ConfirmPassword) == true)
            {
                case true:
                    lblPasswordMatch.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    break;
                case false:
                    lblPasswordMatch.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: `lblFullNameError.Visibility = registerControl.Valid_FullName(student.Student_Name) ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible` ? use a fucntion that returns Visibility.Visible or Visibility.Hidden based on true/false input.  Use Binding with ValueConverters in Xaml to get a visible value, ....

Comment: The best approach would be to set the values to properties in a viewmodel and bind them to the visibility properties in the xaml via BooleanToVisibilityConverter. This would be more maintainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your `switch` statement to a one-liner, using [`ternary operator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator),

```
lblFullNameError.Visibility = registerControl.Valid_FullName(student.Student_Name)  
                  ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
```

You can apply same logic for rest of the switch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to replacing the `switch` statement with the ternary operator (as shown in Prasad's answer), you can also encapsulate the logic into a method:

```
void ToggleError(bool isDataValid, Label errorLabel)
{
    errorLabel.Visibility = isDataValid ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
}
```

and use it as follows:

```
ToggleError(registerControl.Valid_FullName(student.Student_Name), lblFullNameError);
ToggleError(registerControl.Valid_Email(student.Student_Email), lblEmailError);
...
```

This way, you don't have to repeat `Visibility.Hidden` and `Visibility.Visible` in every single line. It's also more maintainable: If you ever want to *change* the way you display error messages, you only need to modify a single method.